# SymLink for "/home/martin" in another disk of same machine

Tags: home-directory, symbolic-link

I'm looking for a solution for the problem like below.

What ever file or DIR that i put in `/home/martin` DIR, should land in `/home-extended/martin` DIR.

Reason behind this, is `/home` DIR has only 2 GB space and every time am running out of space.

I'm trying like below to get this done but it it is not working as expected.

```
ln -s /home/martin /home-extended/martin
```

Could you please through your expertise to get this working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way around:

`ln -s [target] [linkname]`, so in your case:

`ln -s /home-extended/martin /home/martin`.

Other than that, it should work fine. First, copy your stuff to `/home-extended`. Use `rsync` to check and doublecheck that you haven't missed anything. Then, `rm -R /home/martin`, and issue the command above. You should not need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Since `/home` is owned by root, you'll probably need to use `sudo`.